# Rails/ActiveRecord: joining first association only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Session
  has_many :events
end

class Event
  belongs_to :session

  # referrer column
end
```

Each `event` has a `referrer` column, but I'm only interested in the original (first) referrer for the `session`.  So I'd like to be able to join the first `event` to the `session`.  Is this possible with ActiveRecord?

EDIT:

To clarify, I'd like to pull a list of sessions and join the sessions' events.  However, rather than joining ALL of the events, I'd like just the FIRST event (as in the first created).

```
Session.joins(:events) # but I don't want to join all events, just the first one, so I can access the first event's referrer column.
```

Comment: I've trying to do the same question. Any luck with this ever?

Answer (score -1):

Of cause thats possible. What you need is a foreign key in the events table. That should be called session_id and it will automaticly be set when you pass by a session. Like that:

```
event.session=Session.first
```

To add a session_id column to the events table you need to generate a migration

```
rails g migration addSessionIdToEvents
```

And add a column...

```
def self.up<br />
  add_column :events, :session_id, :integer<br />
end
```

And then migrate it

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question (my fault).  Please see edited question.